# With 2-sample bootstrap testing, why pool treatment with control samples?

Tags: bootstrap, pooling, two-sample

I have data from a randomized experiment. Members of the treatment group received a treatment, members of the control group did not.

I want to test differences in distributions of ordinal outcomes across the two groups, so I am using Mann-Whitney and Kolmogoriv 2-sample test statistics.

The outcomes of interest are ordinal, discrete, and highly skewed. Furthermore the sampling design is complex (stratified).

Thus, I need to bootstrap the distributions of the MW and KS statistics under the null hypothesis of no treatment effect.

Efron and Tibshirani, in "Intro the the Bootstrap", chapter 16, say to:

1. Pool the two groups
2. Draw draw bootstrap samples (with replacement) from the pool, with a first sample of size equal to that of the original treatments, and with a second sample of size equal to the original controls (replicating the complex sampling done originally).

My question is: *Why not draw the bootstrap samples only from the control group (for whom the null hypothesis of "no treatment effect" certainly is applicable)?*

After all, if there is a treatment effect, then pooling the treatment and control groups for bootstrapping would result in bootstrapped distributions of the test statistics that do not correspond with the bootstrapped distributions under the null of no treatment effect. And this would seem to decrease the power of the approach to detect treatment effects.

Instead, it seems to me that I should draw the paired bootstrap samples only from the control group, ensuring that the resulting distributions are that of the statistics under the null hypothesis of no treatment effect.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your reference appears to be discussing a permutation test, rather than a bootstrap procedure. Efron and Tibshirani are not just two goofballs writing about statistics on the internet, so I confess my surprise about what appears to be a mistake. Have you, perhaps, omitted some information from the reference? (Is this comment in a chapter or section on permutation testing, for instance, that is compared to bootstrap?) // If you have a complex experimental design, I do not see how your bootstrap considers the design. Given that you're bootstrapping because of the DoE, isn't this a problem?

Comment: Thank you so much. ET are surely not mistaken. But why is pooling is appropriate (p. 91 calls it "natural [and] ad hoc"], when Cs are representative of the population under the null, but Ts may not be? // ET Chaps. 15 "Permutation Tests" and 16 "Hypothesis testing with the Bootstrap" both pool the two samples and then permute/bootstrap. // My bootstrap procedure follows ET pp. 88-92 in replicating the original complex sample design for the T and C samples (SRS in each stratum, with original stratum n), then applying the each obs.' original sampling weight to compute test statistics.